# Build a query, storing fragments in variables

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

I am trying to make something seemingly trivial to work, but i can't make it compile. I not able to store part of the SQL in a local variable:

```
val sql = select.from(Post as p).where.eq(p.id, id)
if (lock)
    sql.forUpdate
else
    sql
```

It complains

```
Error:(44, 17) type mismatch;
found   : scalikejdbc.PagingSQLBuilder[Nothing]
required: scalikejdbc.SQLBuilder[A]
Note: Nothing <: A, but trait SQLBuilder is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
withSQL {
```

Even this does not work:

```
withSQL {
    if (lock)
        select.from(Post as p).where.eq(p.id, id).forUpdate
    else
        select.from(Post as p).where.eq(p.id, id)
}
```

Does anybody have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: can you also provide signature of the function? looks like some types mismatch between returned value and function signature

Comment: this is inside the repl :( (no function/methods)